# Python Unittest: Error False is not true. Matching encrypted password with normal password. Crypt

Tags: python, unit-testing, boolean, passwords, crypt

I'm making a "password checker" which matches a password with an encrypted password out of a random passwords list (these passwords are not real).
It has to pass a unittest created by my teacher.

```
def checkPassword(pswd, cpswd):

hallo = crypt.crypt(pswd, salt=cpswd)
if hallo == cpswd:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

This is the part of the unittest which raises an error.

```
    def test_empty(self):
  
    self.assertTrue(opg_rh.checkPassword('', ''))
    self.assertTrue(opg_rh.checkPassword('', 'zqN6spSQhii2U'))

    def test_pdf_1(self):
    
    self.assertTrue(opg_rh.checkPassword('test', 'npDnXtpN5py4U'))
    self.assertFalse(opg_rh.checkPassword('test', '2Y8H2JzGziJ0M'))
```

The error I get =
def test_empty(self):
self.assertTrue(opg_rh.checkPassword('', ''))
AssertionError: False is not true

Does anyone know what's wrong in my code? I just can't figure it out

Comment: I doubt you should be using the password to check against as the salt.

Answer (score 0):

If the `test_empty(..)` function in the unit test is failing, it means the requirement expects you to handle for empty password cases. That means when the user provides an empty password at any point, you should always return either True or Fales (depending on what your teacher expects).

To fix this try handling an empty password case to always return True (that means you only attempt to hash the provided string if it isn't empty):

```py
def checkPassword(pswd, cpswd):
  if pswd == '' or cpswd == '':
    return True

  hallo = crypt.crypt(pswd, salt=cpswd)
  if hallo == cpswd:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```